# How to classify my data frame numeric values into positive and negative characters

Tags: r

I have a dataframe called `sentiments`:

```
sentiments <- data.frame(vals = c(0.2425356,0.4472136,0.4472136,0.0000000,0.0000000,0.4472136,0.4472136,
                              0.4472136,0.4472136,0.0000000,0.0000000,0.0000000,0.8956686,0.0000000, 
                              0.5692100,0.0000000,0.0000000,0.5692100,0.0000000,0.0000000,0.3535534,0.0000000,0.5000000,0.0000000,0.9333333,
                              0.3015113,0.3015113,0.4472136,0.0000000,0.7071068,0.4472136,0.3015113,0.0000000,0.4472136,0.4472136,0.9333333,
                              -0.4365641,0.2500000,0.0000000,0.0000000,0.0000000,0.0000000,0.2672612,-0.5773503,0.3015113,0.2672612,0.0000000,0.0000000,0.3333333))
```

When I issue the command :

```
sentiments[["polarity"]] <- cut(sentiments[49,], 
                                c(-0.64,0.0,1.2), 
                                labels = c("negative","positive"))

table(sentiments$polarity)
# negative positive 
# 0        49
```

I am seeing that my condition is not applied for cutting the dataframe, as 
all the values are changed into positive. I want to classify all the negative values "negative" and all the values above zero as positive.
Appreciate your response.

Comment: Please provide a simple reproducible example in future. No one is gonna format more than 100 rows of data to make it readable or reproducible.

Comment: HI Adam,  I have edited my submission for fewer data rows.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `cut()` only on the 49th line of sentiments: `sentiments[49,]`.

Use instead:

```
sentiments[["polarity"]] <- cut(sentiments[,1], 
                            c(-0.64,0.0,1.2), 
                            labels = c("negative","positive"))
table(sentiments$polarity)
# negative positive 
# 22       27
```

Comment: That solved my issue. Thanks for your quick help Ken